# How to Run a bash script within python pycharm command line?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to run bash `script.sh` file in Python.
I tried running it through following code:

```
subprocess.call("script.sh", shell=True)
```

but it runs the script outside python and asks Windows application to run this file.

I want this `script.sh` to be run in Python command line.
I want Python to run this script.

Comment: How can Python run a shell script?

Comment: You are running on windows? This runs cmd.exe which runs your program. Set shell=False and it will run it directly... but either way, its got to call a program that understands sh syntax. That doesn't happen natively on windows so you need something like cygwin or gitbash. Alternately you can rewrite the script in python and run that.

Comment: Yes im on windows but im using python compiler pycharm and i have installed python for windows already.doesnt python itself supports bash? ^

Comment: i want bash script outputs on pycharm commandline. thats it.

Comment: No, python itself knows nothing of bash. its a different syntax.

Comment: how does linux run it then?? 
Is there anyway that i can run this bash script inside python. installing some thirdparty app that support bash for windows?:s

Comment: [Cygwin](https://www.google.com/search?q=cygwin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) or [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)

Comment: If you don't have a bash-like shell on windows yet, there are several choices. You may want to do some research. On windows 10 there is https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/. cygwin is popular https://www.cygwin.com/. Then there is git bash https://www.udemy.com/git-bash//

Comment: so i finally installed cygwin and it does works thanks @tdelaney

Comment: The duplicate apparently doesn't solve the actual problem you were attempting to resolve, but I'm hoping the duplicate will be useful for future visitors.

Comment: @triplee im trying to access the commandline in python i did that using os.system("cmd.exe"). it showed me the commandline but at the starting it gives me these errors
 bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell

Comment: This sounds like Windows craziness, rather than Bash or Python craziness.  Your question sounds more and more like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at every new turn.  What are you *actually* trying to accomplish, and can you simplify the problem to one where coincidental problems are removed?  See also how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Import the library OS and then use `os.system`:

```
import os

os.system('bash')
```

Comment: This does works but it asks for windows application to run the bash file. 
while what i am trying to do is run is bash file within pycharm command line.

Comment: that's right (I didn't read the whole question), this run in linux (I've no idea of windows), in linux I added the vte widget and then run scripts in my program: self.terminal.feed_child("sh test2\n",len("sh test2\n"))